# Using HTTP/2 endpoint in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, spdy, http2

Is there a way to hit HTTP/2 / SPDY endpoints and get response in  WP8 or WP8.1 or W8.1 application? Have been looking at multiple places but could not find anything relevant.